# StringLengthAttribute no error

Tags: c#

I'm in Visual studio in C# project (no pattern) and I want to implement a `StringLengthAttribute` error.

```
public class Person  
{    
   [StringLength(2, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLengthError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))] 
   public string Name { get; set; }  
}
```

I added in my `resource.resx` the `StringLengthError` with value

But when I do in a method

```
Person person = new Person(); 
person.Name = "Too Longer Name";
```

There is no error ?! How can I catch this one ?

Thx for your help

Comment: do you need a class to validate the length of the name?

Comment: no i need a way to control what another dev can put in the property name i don't want a lengh > 2

Answer (score 1):

`StringLengthAttribute` tells some code that looks for `StringLengthAttribute`, such as a validation engine, what the maximum length of the string can be. It does not prevent you from assigning a longer string to that field or property.

Comment: Oh thank's, so how can I throw an exception when another developer use my property and if he tries to assigning a longer string plz ? if it's possible i would have an automatic solution to implement that in class who own around 150 fields...

Comment: Write validation code in your setter, instead of using an autoproperty.

Comment: There is not another possiblity ? Because if i refactor 150 fields that will be exhausted

Comment: So i think that there is no possibility except this one thank's for your help